# Allure and parallel test execution - listener is adding 5sec before next test starts

Tags: maven, junit4, allure

I have a problem with Allure listener (https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/#_java). I can't execut tests in parallel mode. Here is code:

Test class (class content):

```
    public class Parallel {

    @Test
    public void test1() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Suite class:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({Parallel.class})
public class ParallelSuite {

}
```

Tests are running via mvn:

```
mvn clean compile test-compile -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dtest=ParallelSuite test
```

Parallel test execution from pom.xml:

```
<parallel>suitesAndMethods</parallel>
<useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
```

When I run this tests I got printed [all is OK]:

```
Fri Nov 17 13:45:07 CET 2017
Fri Nov 17 13:45:07 CET 2017
Fri Nov 17 13:45:07 CET 2017
```

Here I can see that all 3 tests are executed in parallel. But when I enable Allure listener every test execution is shifted for 2sec. So, tests are executed in sequential order instead in parallel.

Here is configuration for listener from pom.xml:

```
<argLine>
-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
```

And here is output where are times logged:

```
Fri Nov 17 13:55:58 CET 2017
Fri Nov 17 13:56:03 CET 2017
Fri Nov 17 13:56:08 CET 2017
```

How to setup Allure listener to execute tests in parallel mode?
[Allure demo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FutOt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Allure listener should now affect parallel execution at all. Can you share full `pom.xml`?

I have created example projects with your data, and it seems to work fine:
https://github.com/letsrokk/stackoverflow-examples/tree/master/allure-junit-parallel

```
[INFO] Running com.github.letsrokk.suites.Parallel
Mon Nov 20 16:34:12 CET 2017
Mon Nov 20 16:34:12 CET 2017
Mon Nov 20 16:34:12 CET 2017
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.098 s - in com.github.letsrokk.suites.Parallel
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

            <groupId>me.fra</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-tests</artifactId>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <name>api-tests</name>

            <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
                <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
            </properties>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>Central Repository</name>
                    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>

            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <releases>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>Central Repository</name>
                    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>

            <dependencies>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.12</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                    <version>1.11</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-junit4 -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0-BETA19</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-maven -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.25</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                    <version>20171018</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/ST4 -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ST4</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.8</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcabi/jcabi-matchers -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcabi-matchers</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <version>1.16.18</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.awaitility/awaitility -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
                    <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fluttercode.datafactory/datafactory -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.fluttercode.datafactory</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datafactory</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/pl.pragmatists/JUnitParams -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
                    <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ec2 -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ec2</artifactId>
                    <version>1.11.232</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                <testOutputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <testResources>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                    </testResource>
                </testResources>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                <finalName>api-tests-1.0-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-compile</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-testCompile</id>
                                <phase>test-compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                            <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.20</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-test</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                            <parallel>suitesAndMethods</parallel>
                            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                            <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                            <argLine>
                                -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                            </argLine>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>listener</name>
                                    <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                                    <value>${basedir}/target/allure-results</value>
                                </property>
                                <property>
                                    <name>allure.link.tms.pattern</name>
                                    <value>https://demohq.atlassian.net/browse/{}</value>
                                </property>
                                <property>
                                    <name>allure.link.issue.pattern</name>
                                    <value>https://app.asana.com/0/{}/f</value>
                                </property>
                            </systemProperties>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </project>
```

Here is full pom.xml. Hope it can help you.